# How do I navigate between pages in my app without having the main page overlay the original?

Tags: android

I am extremely new to programming. I just started today in Android Studio, and I'm trying to figure out what I did wrong here. So I watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ju837bQOBfg and I did exactly what he said. I got the navigation drawer working, but the problem is that the main page displays "Hello World" and when I navigate to the next page, the "Hello World" remains on top of the text of the newly opened page. I can't figure out how to get it so that the front page will disappear once I navigate to a different page.

Comment: post your xml mainActivity and fragments code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, navigation drawers use fragments to change between pages. One of the reasons for that is that if we press the back button on the phone after opening a number of pages in the app in any order, it'll still be able to backtrack. That means, it'll go back in the exact order. So, I believe it's better to use fragments in navigation drawers instead of separate activities like how you want it.

Comment: Ohh you just wanted that hello world to be removed? So just do as Bruno explained. Hello world is displaying in every page because that is the main activity and all the other pages you're opening are fragments. So when the main activity still has the hello world, it'll display it in all it's fragments. Just removing that line will do the trick

Comment: No I don't just want the "Hello World," removed, because if I do it will open up to a blank page when the app starts up, which I don't want. I want it to open up to my home page which is one of the navigation tabs

Comment: So, copy the contents of the starting page to a new fragment. And then delete all the contents from the main page. So now, the main page will be blank. Now code such that on app start up, the new fragment will open up. Now you'll still have all the contents.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from **contente_main.xml**:

```
<TextView
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:text="Hello World!"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try checking the layout xml files, they come with a pre-loaded textview, try removing them...